# Convert an Infopath form to PDF

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

We have designed an Infopath Form and published as a document template on a library. Now, we would like to add a feature to export the InfoPath Form details to PDF or publish the InfoPath Form as PDF from SharePoint 2010. This is a browser enabled Infopath Form.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/8746.aspx?PageIndex=2

Answer (score 0):

you can only publish form to PDF (or print to PDF). There is no direct way to convert InfoPath form to PDF form. Still, you should remember about your investments. Is it really cheaper to convert (possibly outdated) form to another format? Probably, it is easier and faster to create new form from scrath in PDF format?

Anyway, if you are looking for InfoPath alternatives, do not miss questionnaire published by InfoPath Replacement Center www.infopathreplacementcenter.com It can help you find all the required answers, when looking for InfoPath replacement